# Does stackapplet support an http proxy ?

Tags: support, stackapplet

I installed stackapplet on Ubuntu desktop 10.04 from their PPA. This installed stackapplet version 1.5+151~lucid1. This is my computer at work and it is behind an http proxy. I couldn't find anywhere to add that in the stackapplet configuration and I couldn't find any information about if it was using the system proxy config or not.

My problem is that I can add some accounts but nothing else happens and I never see the results. When I click on the stackapplet icon, the "Accounts" section is grayed out and there are no accounts shown. However I can see the accounts when I go in the settings web interface where I added them.

Comment: It's strange that you can't see the accounts in the menu. I'll try to see if I can fix the proxy issue.